# Position fixed by different screen resolution

Tags: css, position

I have problem with the fixed div box with different screen size, the box is look perfect when the resolution is in 1366*768, but if the screen goes to bigger or smaller resolution, the box is `running out` of its position, which is not aligned with the container, as illustrate of the below image.

Could it be properly place and align the box with different screen resolution?

*Note: The div box will shrink to edge when the page is scrolling down.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Fixed div:**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalBox">
    <div class="adv"><span">Big Hi to World</span></div>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 1054px;
}

.adv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 12px;
    right: 12%;
    width: 230px;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: #348cb2;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9998;
}
.adv:hover {
    background-color: #6fc7bb;
}
.adv span {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px;
    line-height: 110%;
}
.adv-ts {
    right: 0;
    width: 48px; 
    height: 48px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.adv-ts span {
    display: none;
}
.adv-ts:after {
    content: "Hi";
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 13px 11px;
    display: block;
}
```

Appreciate for solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

With each screen size change the position of the adv

Comment: Thanks bro!! I have to style all different min-width resolution, but anyway its sort the problem.